# Creating ggplot geom_point() with position dodge 's-shape'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot like the one below. I'd like the order the points in each category in such a way that they form an s-shape. Is it possible to do this in ggplot?

[image]

Similar data available [here](https://gist.github.com/wudustan/57deecdaefa035c1ecabf930afde295a)

What I have so far:

```
somatic.variants <- read.delim("data/Lawrence.S2.txt", stringsAsFactors=T)
cancer_rates <- tapply(somatic.variants$logn_coding_mutations, somatic.variants$tumor_type, median)
cancer_rates <- cancer_rates[order(cancer_rates, decreasing=F)]
somatic.variants$tumor_type <- factor(somatic.variants$tumor_type, levels = names(cancer_rates))

library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
ggplot(data = somatic.variants,
       mapping = aes(x = tumor_type,
                     y = log10(n_coding_mutations))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2()) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c(0,10,100,1000,10000), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_stripped_cols() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 1, size = 12),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  labs(y = "Coding mutations count") +
  stat_summary(fun = median,
               geom="crossbar",
               size = 0.25,
               width = 0.9,
               group = 1,
               show.legend = FALSE,
               color = "#FF0000")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by

1. grouping the data by x-axis categories
2. arranging by the y-axis value

which ensures that the points are plotted in ascending order of the values for each category.

```r
somatic.variants <- read.delim("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wudustan/57deecdaefa035c1ecabf930afde295a/raw/1594d51a1e3b52f674ff746caace3231fd31910a/Lawrence.S2.txt", stringsAsFactors=T)
cancer_rates <- tapply(somatic.variants$logn_coding_mutations, somatic.variants$tumor_type, median)
cancer_rates <- cancer_rates[order(cancer_rates, decreasing=F)]
somatic.variants$tumor_type <- factor(somatic.variants$tumor_type, levels = names(cancer_rates))

library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(dplyr)

somatic.variants <- somatic.variants %>% 
  group_by(tumor_type) %>% 
  arrange(n_coding_mutations)

ggplot(data = somatic.variants,
       mapping = aes(x = tumor_type,
                     y = log10(n_coding_mutations))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2(.9), size = .25) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c(0,10,100,1000,10000), expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_stripped_cols() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 1, size = 12),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  labs(y = "Coding mutations count") +
  stat_summary(fun = median,
               geom="crossbar",
               size = 0.25,
               width = 0.9,
               group = 1,
               show.legend = FALSE,
               color = "#FF0000")
#> Warning: Removed 29 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Does exactly what I wanted.